# gz files reading in R4.3.1

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build a shiny app with a prediction model, the app works when I execute it in RStudio, using a RData file (25Mo), but when I deploy it on shiny ios, it deconnects from the server immediatly.
So I tried to work with a gz file (.rds.gz, 5Mo), but I don't know how to read it. When I use gunzip function, it creates a new 25Mo file in the directory.
I tried this :

```
  con <- gzfile("tri_naiveBayes.rds.gz", "rb")
  tri_naiveBayes <- readRDS(con)
  close(con)
```

but when I run the 2nd line, I get this error : Error in readRDS(con) : unknown input format

Do you know how to read properly the gz file ?
Or is there a way to deploy the app, with the original .RData file (25Mo) on shiny server.

Thank you

Comment: A few suggestions - did you check the logs e.g. `https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/application/<your app id>/logs` when you tried the first time round? Have you tried `readRDS(gzfile("tri_naiveBayes.rds.gz", "rb"))` ?

Comment: Regarding `shinyapps.io`: I think this is not possible to create files from `shiny` app when deployed on `shinyapps.io`, i.e. I don't know what exactly what you are doing, but if you deploy app, and then write some file, I think this won't work. You should deploy the app *with* the file already existed (i.e. deploy app with the data) and then it will be (but I'm not sure!) possible to modify this file. This is limit on `shinyapps.io`, if you would have your own server, you should be able to *create* new files.